# User control type not defined

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm having trouble adding user controls to my project.

1. I right-click on my project and select **Add -> User Control...**
2. I then click **Add**
3. I drag a label onto the new user control, and save it.
4. I build the project, go back to my main form, and drag the control from the **Components** tab in the Toolbox onto the form.

I see the control, but I get an error:

```
Type 'crm.UserControl1' is not defined.
```

If I do this with a blank project, it works. I'm not familiar enough with vb.net or visual studio to understand what's going wrong.

If I double-click the error, it brings me to this line in the generated designer code for the form:

```
Me.UserControl11 = New crm.UserControl1()
```

and says that `crm.UserControl1` is not defined. If I change it to `Global.crm.UserControl1`, it works, but obviously this code is overwritten when I fiddle with the designer.

Any ideas, or pointers to get me started in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

My main form had the same name as the root namespace. This is what caused the problem.

Comment: Wow, thanks... this saves me some serious headache.. such a stooooped error!\

Comment: Unfortunately, my main form *doesn't* have the same name as the root namespace, so this problem still exists for me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of late to the party with this one but I had this problem and I think that the issue was due to the controls being built in a more recent framework than the one that I was using.

Basically my custom controls were built in 4.7, but my project was being built in 4.5.1

Once I changed the current build so that they both were the same it compiled happily.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is kind of accessibility issue because you are able to solve the issue when you try to access the object globally. I think when you drag and drop the control, the definition codes of the control in the designer class automatically generated with private accessibility but I don't know why. You could try to change it as public. I hope this will work.

Comment: I don't see any such setting in the properties panel of the control. Do you know where I could change that setting?

Answer (score 0):

Way late to this party. I fixed it by referencing it in the aspx page with the following as it was missing.

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/mycontrolname.ascx" TagPrefix="ucControl" TagName="MyControl" %>
```